# Windows spotlight not working on secure logon (requires ctrl+alt+del to logon)

Tags: windows-10-v1803, windows-spotlight

How do I enable windows spotlight when secure logon (requires ctrl+alt+del to logon) is enabled? It seems that whenever secure logon is enabled, spotlight ceases to work. Any fix would be highly appreciated.

Please note that my system is running Win10 Enterprise x64 version 1803.

Comment: Try in regedit to navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System` and set `DisableLockScreenAppNotifications` to `0`. If it doesn't exist, create it as DWORD 32-bit.

Comment: I'm afraid that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my environment, Win10 Pro x64 version 1803. I enable secure logon, then I set windows spotlight, I can see the setting works when I click "log off".The third part of the screenshot shows the "weather" in the lower left corner.

Sorry, my display language is Chinese. I hope you can understand what I mean.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do wallpapers change periodically for you? They do not for me.

Comment: When there is a network connection, the wallpaper will be changed. But I didn't pay attention to the change frequency.

Comment: I have used the same settings. It was not working previously but now everything is working fine.
Anyway, I thank you for your help. :)

Comment: You are welcome, I am so glad the information is useful.